# NestJS cant resolve Service / Schema dependency

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, backend

I currently am building a simple nestjs module. I read through the docs and essentially followed their recommendations. But for some reason, the module I am currently working on is not getting resolved by Nest JS at the moment I introduce my Mongoose schema to a service.

#### The Problem:

- The setup is currently pretty simple, I open two DB connections in the root app module, and only import there a module called "private".
- The Private module on the other hand imports the module (Properties) that makes me problems.
- Here comes the weird part: When commenting out schema-related logic in the service files (of PropertiesService), everything compiles fine, but when uncommenting it I am getting this error:

`2024-03-08 23:07:46 [Nest] 545  - 03/08/2024, 10:07:46 PM   ERROR [ExceptionHandler] Nest can't resolve dependencies of the PropertiesService (?). Please make sure that the argument "PropertyModel" at index [0] is available in the PropertiesModule context.`

So when the service uses the schemas like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import {
  Property,
  PropertyDocument,
} from 'src/private/properties/properties.schema';

@Injectable()
export class PropertiesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Property.name)
    private propertyModel: Model<PropertyDocument>,
  ) {}

  createProperty() {
    const myTestObject = new this.propertyModel({ name: 'MyTestString' });
    return myTestObject.save();
  }
  getPropertyCollection() {
    return 'myCollection';
  }
  updateProperty() {}
  deleteProperty() {}
}
```

It will throw the above error.

But when I am commenting out the related logic, it compiles...

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import {
  Property,
  PropertyDocument,
} from 'src/private/properties/properties.schema';

@Injectable()
export class PropertiesService {
  // constructor(
  //   @InjectModel(Property.name)
  //   private propertyModel: Model<PropertyDocument>,
  // ) {}

  createProperty() {
    // const myTestObject = new this.propertyModel({ name: 'MyTestString' });
    // return myTestObject.save();
  }
  getPropertyCollection() {
    return 'myCollection';
  }
  updateProperty() {}
  deleteProperty() {}
}
```

So it seems the problem must be somewhere here, but I cant figure out why / what is wrong here. Also note that while PropertiesService is not using the schema in that moment, the PropertyModule is still using them, so I am pretty sure the error must be in this service file... The rest of the code:

https://github.com/Samulsen/PRO-datc-server/tree/DevCommit_PropertiesApi

#### What did I try?

- For starters, I banged my head several times against the wall and started wondering if I should become a farmer.
- Except for the usual procedure, I read through the docs here where they show this very simple example with the cats API: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb.
- I tried to figure the issue out with ChatGPT / Copilot but he seems to be on vacation or something, only nonsense came out of him...
- This is my second nightly shift trying to figure this out, I am just tired and would appreciate help. Its probably some stupid beginners problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use a named database (found this out by checking your repository), you need to use that name in the `@InjectModel()` as well, as the second parameter. This is due to how Nest tracks the injection tokens across multiple databases, so it knows which one to inject. Your `@InjectModel()` should look like `@InejctModel(Property.name, 'dictDB')`

Comment: Hey, thank you so so much, it resolved the Issue!!! I almost lost my mind yesterday with that.... Thx again! Best Sam